# Privacy concerns regarding online (web-based) genealogy software

Tags: ancestry.com, website, privacy

I'm a bit conflicted about asking this question, but it has been bothering me so why not ask?

I recently attended a genealogy workshop where the instructor said that he would NEVER use THE major online genealogy website (notice how I'm cleverly avoiding the actual name).

His rationale was "because they will willingly sell my data and my research" thus profiting from my work without my knowledge or consent. Moreover, they would be "invading" my privacy.

While I had never considered this to be an issue, or to be something I should be concerned about, I wondering if there is something that I'm not recognizing.

Comment: They could hardly be selling your research without your consent -- by putting it on the website, you're consenting to have them use it within their terms and conditions... And they couldn't be doing it without your knowledge for the same reason.  They may well be profiting from it (they wouldn't host it if they weren't) but they're not lying to you about what they're doing with it.

Comment: Also, how can they be 'invading your privacy' when they only know what you choose to tell them?  You control what information you give them (and yes, you might naively give them more than you intended, but it's on you to do the due diligence). Plus most research is based on publicly available data so how can that be private? (You might not want to give away the fruits of your labours, but that's a different question). And making DNA data available is a whole other can of worms.

Comment: Agreed that DNA is a whole 'nuther thing, but the focus was on just genealogic records and relationships. I can see his point if a user scans a private letter or a picture into a gallery of a **public** tree, that image is available to all other users, and  having done so, there should be no expectation of privacy. (In fact access to other's public galleries is a selling point for membership). OTOH, if a subscriber has a **private tree** there should be an expectation of privacy. Have there been any instances where **private tree** data been sold or otherwise released?

Comment: I'm not aware of any; doesn't mean it hasn't happened -- but I suspect there would be an almighty visible stink it it had happened. I thoroughly cleanse my data of all living people (or possible-living people)  before I publish it and NEVER include source images or photos -- i.e. I take responsibility for the privacy of my relatives, not delegating it to some company.

Comment: Several points: (1) Guidelines of leading genealogy organizations state that genealogists should not post information about living people online (or otherwise share it) without permission from those living people; (2) DNA is a huge issue because it exposes all of your extended family; (3) Some genealogy websites are also more general data brokers, they obtain and aggregate information about living people and make it available; (4) Yes, for-profit companies profit from your submissions.

Comment: Bottom line on privacy: Never share information about living people without their clear consent (and understanding of the potential ways their information could be used, once shared), and be very cautious if you choose to post any of your own personal information. General historical genealogical research, once shared or posted publicly, is largely beyond your control... but by all means share it if it's your goal to have the history more widely known, recognizing that others will re-post it (often without attribution).

Comment: @pseudon (1) you said - "some websites ...are data brokers", can you give examples?, second followup - Is census data (1940 and earlier) on living persons privileged or protected?

Comment: @BobE Without getting too specific about data brokers, one way to see is to do a search for yourself or close family on any given genealogy site and see what kinds of records come up. I have found commercial records of myself on genealogy sites; not user-submitted and not of a genealogical nature.

Comment: @BobE Yes, 1940 census is available, so you could say that there's no limitation in sharing. But there is an argument to be made that making it easier to find information on living people is not good for their privacy. For example, let's say I collect up a ton of "public" records on a living person and publish them all in one place, indexed by search engines and easy to find. Not friendly at all for a bunch of reasons. They could be upset. They could be victims trying to keep a low profile. I would urge caution and sensitivity. Best to ask the person affected.

Comment: Privacy was not the Instructor's point - except for his own. His point was that Ancestry "profit" from his research. I presume that he would be happy to pay for someone to publish a book of his research, but he is not happy for Ancestry to publish it for free (the extra cost of using their tree being zero). Either way the data is out there. The book publisher will also make a profit. Why is that not immoral?

Comment: @AdrianB38 - "privacy" - except that not what he said. On your second point, have there been any examples of where Ancestry published someone's work without compensation or attribution. (perhaps I have a understanding of "publish" than you).  Or is the concern that someday in the future, Ancestry **might** provide public access to **private** family trees?

Comment: I can't confirm that something has never happened. However, Ancestry's User Interface shows the Ancestry user name against each tree. I really have no idea what people fear about Ancestry. I think that people simply object to money being brought into the equation, thinking that everything should be free, because if Family Search can do it, why can't Ancestry? FS, of course, profits in a different way.

Comment: @AdrianB38 - I'm sorry if I was unclear, I was asking if it **has** been reported that something **had** happened. (Obviously it is nearly impossible to state that something has **never** happened.

Comment: But it's equally impossible for me to know whether there's been any such report! I don't have access to Ancestry's error reporting, nor have I read all the mailing lists in all the world. All I can say is that I don't remember seeing any credible suggestions of unattributed use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your instructor has turned things quite around.

When a person signs up to an online genealogy website, or any website or social site for that matter, there is an agreement that must be approved, that states what the company may do. (Ignore for now that most people don't read this and just check the box.) If the person checks the box, then they have given consent and have knowledge of what the company could do with their data.

With regards to privacy, if a person puts their own family tree or any other social information on a public site, then they are effectively giving up their privacy themselves.

So if your instructor wants to be paranoid, and think everyone, especially the big companies, are after him, he can stay off the Internet and spend the rest of his life trying to expunge his name from government records and online directories.

If his concerns were truly an issue, then there would be millions of people who would be finding their data in other repositories due to sales and would be complaining of privacy invasion. But there aren't. His presumption is false.